How many jumuahs can we miss consequently
Salam, I have been missing jummmahs for about 3 weeks now. My mother doesnt allow me as I am in 10th grade(10th grade is a pretty serious grade in India). She says it is not fard to go to jummah prayer. But I have heard somewhere that 2 jummahs can only be missed consequently.
Please share me some scholarly insight on this matter as the following day is friday in India.

Are you asking about a male or female?

Im a male. Eitherway I skipped school today .
